# was-was whispers of satan getting out of control that making me miserble everyday please help me overcome them!

Tags: shaitan

assalamu alaikum,

i been haveing these bad thought about Allah and i know there not true because deep inside me i know for a fact allah is one god i use to be good and now i can't sleep or anything i wish i was like my family so peaceful they don't get these thoughts..idk why me :'( and when i try to think abt allah satan will mess up my moments and i cry and my parents dont know what wrong b/c i havent told them i'm afriad to. And satan tells me your life going to be miserable and every time i think abt this makes my head hurts even worst and i feel like falling out and it feel like satan it trap inside my head cuz he seems to block out everything i do like , pray salah waking up for fajr its very hard i literally can feel the satan in my head and i know its not just a headache. Sometimes it feels like something in my head and when i prays allah it goes to the other side of my brain and it hurts physically i can't concentrate on allah its very hard please help me get the satan out my head!!!! it driving me crazy i cant sleep i wanna cry everyday i need allah to cure me but how if satan trap inside my head he causing me to forget about allah? i wanna be normal like everyone else inshallah.Not to mention sometimes i feel hopeless cuz Satan tells me a lot that you are never going to be forgiven you disobeyed Allah and your going to live in miserable all your life and you have no one to turn to lift this sadness just give up.. :'( i feel tht allah may not forgive me cuz of these thoughts tht causing me to live like this and i feel so bad and all i do is yell the satan to get out my head but he seems to stay inside in cause all types of confusing to my brain :'( please help me !

Comment: recommended for u [Getting started with Satan](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0usGDDlyK7A) remember Allah much, and try to seek some professional help around your place, not only on the internet... I hope that might help...

Comment: The answers here won't help you. To everyone answering: please be extremely cautious. It is clear that we are dealing with a young teenager who's going through some hard times. Depression or other mental illness can set in rather quickly and OP should visit a doctor or a therapist. Anything less than 'consult a doctor'  could actually be harmful.  Aisha, you should tell your parents so that they can help you. Don't try to hide it or be embarrassed

Comment: @masfenix Thank you! Too few people on this site address this type of question like you do.

Answer (score 4):

Wa alaykum salam,

Sister, Satan can't force you to do anything. He can only whisper to you, and whether or not listening to him is fully depend on you.

If you worry about these thoughts like Satan in your head, it will only cause you to more worry. When you get some thoughts like this, please read this below:

> Eûzu billahi mineş-şeytânirracîm. Bismillahirrahmanirrahîm.

Then read **Ayatul Kursi, Felak, Nas**.

If it is really Satan, he won't be able to near around you.

Also, don't despair, read surat 39:53.

**About the physical hurt**, it may be caused by a disease or some inner physical damage. I strongly suggest you to go to a good doctor. But don't panic, it may be caused by your mental stress also. Please go to a doctor.